# How do I test if the first digit of an integer is a 7?

Tags: c#, if-statement, testing

I have had the user enter an integer. I would like to test to see if the first digit is a 7 or not.

```
string enteredValue;
int number;
Console.WriteLine("Enter integer: ");
enteredValue = Console.ReadLine();
number = Int.Parse(enteredValue);
```

The test (to see if the first digit is a 7) can occur before or after I parse the string to an int. If the number is not a 7 have the following occur

```
Console.WriteLine("First digit was not 7");
Console.WriteLine(nRe-enter number ");
```

Comment: did you tried anything ?

Comment: I tried using 

if (number[0] != 7)

and then writing to the console that the first digit was not a 7. This said that I couldn't apply indexing with an int expression. 

I then also tried 
if (enteredValue[0] != "7")

Comment: why `1` when you need `7` to not match..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test it before you parse the string like below:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(enteredValue)
   && enteredValue[0] == '7')
{
    int.TryParse(enteredValue, out number);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("First digit was not 7");
    Console.WriteLine(nRe-enter number ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(enteredValue.charAt(0)!='7')
{
     Console.WriteLine("First digit was not 7");
     Console.WriteLine("nRe-enter number ");
}
```

Comment: Isn't `charAt()` Java/JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

As **enteredValue** is a string and taken from console, may be you need not **additional check for null or empty** if you use **LINQ**.

```
if (enteredValue.FirstOrDefault() == '7')
{
   int.TryParse(enteredValue, out number);
}else
{
   Console.WriteLine("First digit was not 7");
   Console.WriteLine("Re-enter number: ");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Well let's split your need first. 
First step is to find out the first digit of the integer. For this you can simply do the following

```
int firstDigit = Math.Abs(number);
while(firstDigit >= 10)
    firstDigit /= 10;
```

and firstDigit will contain what you need

Now check if it is 7 or not with a if condition

Comment: Since it's a string it would be a lot easier to simply test the first character before parsing as an int

Comment: Actually he asked us help him find out the first digit of an integer. I answered that part.

Comment: you will experience here on SO that most often OP has an issue with expressing the actual issue and it's therefor always a good idea to read the entire post and give an answer that helps solve the problem as best as possible instead of potentially just fixing a problem with a subpar implementation